# Cambiar caracteres de un documento HTML por campos de la base de datos

Tags: sql, sql-server

Lo que estoy intentando hacer es lo siguiente, tengo una tabla con palabras reservadas como se muestra a continuación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

por otro lado tengo un formato html que tiene incluido etiquetas especiales

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y que al momento de obtener el formato este pueda reemplazar las etiquetas especiales por los campos de mi BD.

Nota : la tabla con palabras reservadas no es fijo, es decir puede agregarse mas palabras, al igual que el formato de documento este puede tener una o mas de una etiqueta especial.

El resultado final seria algo así, pero como se observan solo se cambio una etiqueta especial, el query que use para este caso fue
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El resultado final deseado es cambiar las etiquetas especiales por los datos de un trabajador y así para el siguiente...
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

finalmente el query que se realizo no es dinámico, porque si intento hacerlo con subQuery no obtengo el resultado que necesito.

Comment: Puedes editar tu pregunta y colocar el resultado esperado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si he entendido bien lo que necesitas, yo te recomiendo que utilices un [Cursor](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-cursor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) para iterar sobre tu tabla de palabras reservadas y una tabla temporal en la que primero copiaremos los registros a modificar y despues vamos actualizando con los cambios realizados en cada iteración, es decir, con cada palabra reservada.

No conozco las tablas así que ajusta el código, pero seria algo asi:

```
CREATE TABLE #tablaTemporal
(ideTrab int,
desCuer nvarchar(MAX))

INSERT INTO #tablaTemporal
SELECT  ideTrab,
        DesCuer
FROM @FormDocuTrab    

DECLARE @codCamp nvarchar(100)
DECLARE @descCamp nvarchar(100)

DECLARE curs CURSOR FOR
    SELECT codCamp, descCamp
    FROM TablaPalabrasReservadas

OPEN curs
FETCH NEXT FROM curs INTO @codCamp, @descCamp
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
    BEGIN

        UPDATE #tablaTemporal
        SET DesCuer = REPLACE(t1.DesCuer, @descCamp, t2.NomTrab)
        FROM @FormDocuTrab t1
        INNER JOIN M_Trab t2 ON t2.IdeTrab = t1.IdeTrab

    FETCH NEXT FROM curs INTO @codCamp, @descCamp
    END
CLOSE curs;  
DEALLOCATE curs;  

SELECT  ideTrab,
        DesCuer
FROM #tablaTemporal

DROP TABLE #tablaTemporal
```

Comment: agradezco tu ayuda, pero como harías para cambiar mas de una palabra reservada al momento de usar replace porque en un formato existen varias etiquetas como sueldoTrabajador, puesto, doc. identidad etc. y todo eso lo quiero cambiar al momento de de entrar al bucle.

Comment: Puedes anidar los Replace, eso es posible, el problema viene si no sabes qué contiene tu tabla de palabras reservadas. No entiendo que quieres decir con al momento de entrar al bucle. Con el código que te he puesto lo reemplazas todo por las etiquetas de tu tabla.